# Making transparent text in Google Slides

Tags: google-slides, text-formatting

I would like to make my text transparent.

I've found only how to make transparent background which is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: Making text transparent in Google Slides is not currently possible.

Comment: Is it for a link? You could use notes as well. I can't think of any uses for transparent text.

Answer (score 6):

To make transparent text in **Google Slides** : `Insert > Word Art`
Then change the fill and outline colors by clicking on the respective icons and clicking `custom` then changing the transparency level.

Answer (score 5):

While Google Slides does not natively support the functionality of setting opacity on the color of the text, there is a workaround you can use which employs a similar feature which Google Suite does support.

1. Convert text to an image.
2. Import image into Google {Docs,Slides,...} workspace.
3. Edit opacity '%'age under "Image Options".

Currently this is the only way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Fredericka the Great font can work to make the text more transparent, especially if you make the color lighter on the color changing options.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Word Art on Google!

Comment: Welcome. Please describe how this answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, insert word art and write your text there. But remember, it doesn't let you choose the font. It will let you play secret texts on friends and pranks.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! Other answers already mention this; is this really worth posting another time?